# A few tables are still out of sync after running mk-table-sync

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, maatkit

I have 1 master and 2 slaves.    I am using MySQL 5.1.42 on all servers.  I am attempting to use mk-table-checksum to verify that their data is in sync, but I am getting unexpected results on one of the slaves.

First, I generate the checksums on the master like this:

`mk-table-checksum h=localhost --databases MYDB --tables {$table_list} --replicate=MYDB.mk_checksum --chunk-size=10M`

My understanding is that this runs the checksum queries on the master which then propagate via normal replication to the slaves.  So, no locking is needed because the slaves will be at the same logical point in time when they run the checksum queries on themselves.  Is this correct?

Next, to verify that the checksums match, I run this on the master:

`mk-table-checksum --databases MYDB --replicate=IRC.mk_checksum --replicate-check 1 h=localhost,u=maatkit,p=xxxx`

If there are any differences, I repair the slaves like this:

`mk-table-sync --execute --verbose --replicate IRC.mk_checksum h=localhost,u=maatkit,p=xxxx`

After doing all of this, I repaired both slaves with mk-table-sync.  However, everytime I run this sequence (after everything has already been repaired), one slave is perfectly in sync but one slave always has a few tables out of sync.  I am 99.999% sure that the data on the slaves matches, since I repaired everything and the tables were not even updated on the master between runs of the checksum script.  What would cause a few tables to always show out of sync on only one of the slaves?  I am stuck.  Here is the output:

> ```
> Differences on h=x.x.x.x,p=...,u=maatkit
> ```
>
> DB    TBL               CHUNK CNT_DIFF CRC_DIFF BOUNDARIES
>   IRC   product              10        0        1 `product_id` >= 147377 AND `product_id` < 162085
>   IRC   post_order_survey     0        0        1 1=1
>   IRC   mk_heartbeat          0        0        1 1=1
>   IRC   mailing_list          0        0        1 1=1
>   IRC   honey_pot_log         0        0        1 1=1
>   IRC   product              12        0        1 `product_id` >= 176793 AND `product_id` < 191501
>   IRC   product              18        0        1 `product_id` >= 265041
>   IRC   orders               26        0        1 `order_id` >= 694472
>   IRC   orders_product        6        0        1 `op_id` >= 935375

Answer (score 0):

--replicate=MYDB.mk_checksum

--replicate=IRC.mk_checksum

Why the difference?

Comment: sorry, typo. both should be MYDB.

Answer (score -1):

Did you, perchance, post this question to the Maatkit mailing list?  It sounds like a recent thread there.  If it wasn't you, maybe you can hijack that thread.  (I prefer to answer there, I don't track/follow/monitor here).